# How to format list items with HTML in a Master Detail Flow Activity

Tags: android, html, list, master-detail, arrays

I have a Master Detail Flow activity, and in that activity there is a string array. I would like to format my item name string "content" in my list with HTML. However, I am not sure where to declare an HTML method to make this work, but I do know that the strings are called in a public string toString method in the Content.java file

```
public String toString() {
        return (content);       
    }
```

or maybe I could get the list adapter to implement the formatting  which is in my ListFragment.java file

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<ExerciseContent.Exercise>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1, ExerciseContent.ITEMS));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to `HTML` content right?

Comment: I want to format string content with HTML

Comment: You can try `Html.fromHtml("<h2>Your Content</h2>");`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to put content in quotes, content is the name of the string, not the actual string itself

Comment: actually i didn't get your question, please try to explain.

Comment: Ok, so what I want to do is to have a string called content which is a parameter of a string array to be able to be edited with html. This string array represents the names of items, and descriptions in a master detail flow activity

Comment: so you want to edit this content in HTML

Comment: Yes I want to edit a string named content with HTML

Comment: You can use `String` Functions and for `HTML` you can use `Html class` in android as an above example.

Comment: @PratikButani I am not exactly sure where to implement Html class out of the two blocks of code I provided

Answer (score 0):

```
Items item_data[]= null;
Items  item = item_data[position];
ItemHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u><b>" + item.title+ "</b></u>"));
```

Try, these may help you !

Comment: Would this go inside my Content.java file, or inside my ListAdapter in my ListFragment.java file?

Comment: These shall go inside the ListAdapter where your getView()method is called. Let me know if it's working.

Comment: There actually is no getView()method called in the adapter. There actually is a TODO instructing to replace the generated adapter with a real adapter. How would I implement a getView() in the generated adapter?

Comment: Which Adapter are you using ? Cvarier ? and for What purpose are you used for it ?

Comment: Are you familiar with Master/Detail flow? Whenever a new activity with a Master/Detail flow template is created, a ListAdapter is automatically generated in the `DetailFragment.java` file. However I don't think I should bother with that. Maybe the `public String toString()` I stated earlier could be where I could declare a `spannable fromhtml` instead. I'm just not sure how to do that.